# JAVA - Find shortest path between two nodes in a weighted graph (also negative weights)

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, path, bellman-ford

I need an algorithm to find the shortest path between a defined source node and a defined target node.

The input file looks something like this:

```
0 6 1.4    

7 9       

0 1 3.2   
0 2 2.4   
0 3 1.7   
1 2 -2.1  
2 4 1.6   
3 4 1.8  
4 5 1.9  
4 6 1.7  
5 6 -3.1
```

- the first line represents: the first number is the starting node, the second one is the target 
   node and the third one is the maximum weight i could possibly spend
- the second line represents the number of node and arcs
- the other lines represent the description of the arcs with their weights
  // Example: from the node 0 to the node 1 the weight is 3.2.

At the end if there are no possibly paths that cost less than 1.4 (as the first input line gives) the program must return the value 0. If it's possible, it must return 1.

I tried to use the Bellman-Ford algorithm , however it finds shortest distance to all destinations.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Just use Dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: `however it finds shortest distance to all destinations`
that's how shortest-path algorithms work

Comment: Have a look at A* (A-star) algorithm

Comment: @user3437460 No, it doesn't work, he has negative weights.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the Bellman-Ford algorithm and check if the shortest path to the target node has inferior or equal weight to the one specified in the results.

Say `results` is a List object returned from the Bellman-Ford application on the graph speciying a starting node `src`, where `results.get(tgt)` returns the shortest-path weight between nodes `src` and `tgt`.
Say `maxWeight` is the maximum weight you want your shortest-path to weight.

You could do something like this:

```
if(!results.contain(tgt))
    return 0;
if(results.get(tgt) <= maxWeight)
    return 1;
```